# Flutter how to change popup menu item highlight color radius

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a `popup menu button` in Flutter and changed the `corner radius of the menu`. Now when **I touch one of the buttons**, the corners of the **highlight color remain outside**. Is there any way I can change this color or change its radius?

The situation I mentioned is as in the picture.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RoundedRectangleBorder` as its shape and set the `clipBehavior` to either `Clip.antiAlias` or `Clip.hardEdge`.

```dart
PopupMenuButton(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias, // or Clip.hardEdge
  // ...
)
```

[image: Screenshot]